# changing column header values in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, columnheader

I'm using:

```
tableName.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("new header blahhh");
```

to change header values.

After the code executes, the header value only changes once i mouse over the column header
i have NO mouseover events anywhere.

Has anyone else heard of this?
Is there another way i can change header values without this?

Comment: Post some code here, You can refer [MCVE Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"..change header values."*  Why?  Or rather, wouldn't a new model make more sense?

Comment: I dont know what that means, but i'll look into it thankyou!

Comment: why in the world would it behave like that though?!

Answer (score 0):

Force a repaint of the table header:

```
tableName.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("new header blahhh");
tableName.getHeader().repaint();
```

Comment: getHeader() does not seem to exist

Comment: @user3011690, Oops, it looks like I gave you the wrong method name. Anyway, you have had 6 days to look at the API. I'll let you practice your API reading skills by looking for a getter method that returns a JTableHeader. Or you can search for a method name that contains the word "header". Maybe while reading the API you will find other interesting methods you might be able to use in the future.